# Why won't XML DOC comments in a C++ header generate output?

Tags: c++, xml-documentation

I have a C++ project that creates a DLL, let's call it my.dll. Along with it I supply a header named my.h which contains declarations of the functions exported from my.dll. The source code of my.dll #includes the my.h header. I've added XML DOC comments to the function declarations in my.h and set the /doc switch on the cl.exe command line. At compile time one *.xdc file for each *.cpp file but none of them contain the XML DOC comments found in my.h.

It appears the /doc switch on cl.exe only processed XML DOC comments from c/c++ files. Is this true? If not, how to I get it to process XML DOC comments in a header file?

Answer (score -2):

For in-code documentation, I strongly recommend doxygen (uses javadoc format) rather than the proprietary xmldoc format.

Comment: Be that as it may, I'm still curious if Microsoft really doesn't generate XML from the comments in a header.